# Find the 10 documents created before and after a specific document with mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm an inexperienced programmer, and I'm still pretty new to mongoose. Spare me if I'm asking a dumb question.

Let's say I have a collection of 100+ documents. I want to specify one document and find the 10 documents created before and the 10 documents created after that document.

One of the solutions I thought up is something like this:

```
let firstDoc;
let tenBefore;
let tenAfter;

// find the starting document
document.findById(id, function(err, foundDoc){
    if(err) {
        ...
    } else {
        firstDoc = foundDoc;

        // find the 10 documents before
        document
        .find({created_at: {$lt: foundDoc.created_at}})
        .limit(10)
        .exec(function(err, beforeDocs) {
            if(err) {...} else {
            tenBefore = beforeDocs;
            
            // find the 10 documents after
            document
            .find({created_at: {$gt: foundDoc.created_at}})
            .limit(10)
            .exec(function(err, afterDocs) {
                if(err) {...} else {
                tenAfter = afterDocs;
                }
            });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I haven't tried it yet to see if it even works or not, but it obviously isn't the best solution (a horrible one at that) and can be considered callback hell.

If anyone with more experience and knowledge can help me with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES7 you can clean up the call backs with async/await. You can also run the second queries simultaneously with `Promise.all`

```
async function() {
  const foundDoc = await document.findById(id).catch(err => ...);
  const [beforeDocs, afterDocs] = await Promise.all([
    document
        .find({created_at: {$lt: foundDoc.created_at}})
        .sort({created_at: -1}) // sort descending to get latest 10
        .limit(10),
    document
        .find({created_at: {$gt: foundDoc.created_at}})
        .sort({created_at: 1}) // sort ascending to get earliest 10
        .limit(10),
  ]);
}
```

AsyncAwait:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Destructuring:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Promise.all:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

You can also use aggregate to complete all three queries in one request but it's a bit more complicated. This will return the doc you are querying by _id
with two additional array fields `beforeDocs` and `afterDocs`.

Example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/6KeNaCpaifO

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    _id: 5 // use mongoose.Types.ObjectId('YOUROBJECTID')
  }},
  {$lookup: {
    from: "collection",
    as: "beforeDocs",
    let: {
      "parent_created_at": "$created_at"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {$match: {
        // Need to use $expr to access parent created at date
        $expr: {$lt: ["$created_at", "$$parent_created_at"]}
      }},
      {$sort: {created_at: -1}},
      {$limit: 10}
    ]
  }},
  {$lookup: {
    from: "collection",
    as: "afterDocs",
    let: {
      "parent_created_at": "$created_at"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {$match: {
        $expr: {$gt: ["$created_at", "$$parent_created_at"]}
      }},
      {$sort: {created_at: 1}},
      {$limit: 10}
    ]
  }},
])
```